# I'd like to create a searchable table for each table column and one over all search box

Tags: javascript, html, search

I have a basic table consisting of 5 columns, I'd like to create a searchable html site for each column and one over all search box. How can I achieve this?

Here's the code I have so far, it only has the one search box, I'd like to add a search box to each column:

```js
    function myFunction() {
      var input, filter, table, tr, td, i;
      input = document.getElementById("myInput");
      filter = input.value.toUpperCase();
      table = document.getElementById("myTable");
      tr = table.getElementsByTagName("tr");
      for (i = 0; i < tr.length; i++) {
        td = tr[i].getElementsByTagName("td")[0];
        if (td) {
          if (td.innerHTML.toUpperCase().indexOf(filter) > -1) {
            tr[i].style.display = "";
          } else {
            tr[i].style.display = "none";
          }
        }       
      }
    }
```

```css
    * {
      box-sizing: border-box;
    }
    
    #myInput {
      background-image: url('/css/searchicon.png');
      background-position: 10px 10px;
      background-repeat: no-repeat;
      width: 100%;
      font-size: 16px;
      padding: 12px 20px 12px 40px;
      border: 1px solid #ddd;
      margin-bottom: 12px;
    }
    
    #myTable {
      border-collapse: collapse;
      width: 100%;
      border: 1px solid #ddd;
      font-size: 18px;
    }
    
    #myTable th, #myTable td {
      text-align: left;
      padding: 12px;
    }
    
    #myTable tr {
      border-bottom: 1px solid #ddd;
    }
    
    #myTable tr.header, #myTable tr:hover {
      background-color: #f1f1f1;
    }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
    </head>
    <body>
    
    <h2>Washer Search</h2>
    
    <input type="text" id="myInput" onkeyup="myFunction()" placeholder="Search" title="Type in a name">
    
    <table id="myTable">
      <tr class="header">
        <th style="width:10%;">ZIP</th>
        <th style="width:30%;">CITY</th>
        <th style="width:30%;">PHONE</th>
        <th style="width:30%;">EMAIL</th>
        <th style="width:30%;">COMPLETED</th> 
      </tr>
      <tr><td>90048</td> <td>Los Angeles</td> <td>323-000-0000</td> <td>TEST4@hotmail.com</td> <td>May</td></tr>
    <tr><td>33312</td> <td>Dania</td> <td>954-000-0000</td> <td>TEST34@gmail.com</td> <td>May</td></tr>
    <tr><td>33127</td> <td>Miami</td> <td>305-000-0000</td> <td>TEST7@gmail.com</td> <td>July</td></tr>
    
    </table>
     </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: u can achieve that with the help of [dataTables](https://editor.datatables.net/examples/simple/simple)

Comment: When I put the code in the search boxes don't work. I tried this one -- https://datatables.net/examples/api/multi_filter.html

Comment: show us what u have tried so far. we don't know what you have done. so we can't assume ur mistakes.

Comment: I posted the code, when I add "<th><input type="text" name="ZIP" value="Search ZIP" class="search_init" /></th>" for each column, the boxes aren't 'live'

Comment: @MonikaGrabowska  you should use columnsearch method of datatable https://datatables.net/reference/api/column().search()

Comment: @MonikaGrabowska Are you saying you want 5 search boxes for 5 columns?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/20567804/5289704 take a look at that answer.

Answer (score 0):

If you want 5 search boxes for the 5 columns, make 5 similar javascript functions with a small modification. Call each of these functions for the respective search boxes.
Search for this line in your javascript function:

`td = tr[i].getElementsByTagName("td")[0];`

And make that

`td = tr[i].getElementsByTagName("td")[1];`

to search in the second column instead of the first.
You can increment this in each function for your five search boxes. So each searchbox will search for only a particular column.